# add items in the dictionary from another form

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to access my dictionary of another form, but I can not ...

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public DataNode rootNode;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> documents = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        public Form1() {

        }
```

form2.cs

```
public partial class addCapitulo : Form
    {
        Form1 addcapitulo;

        public addCapitulo(Form1 treeList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            addcapitulo = treeList;
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pageGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            addcapitulo.rootNode.Nodes.Add(new DataNode("Testando", pageGuid));
            addcapitulo.documents.Add(pageGuid, addcapitulo.blankRtfText);
        }
    }
```

Error: cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

How can I accomplish this access ? able to access and use the dictionary in any form ...

Answer (score 2):

To access a Static type you need:

```
Form1.documents
```

You cannot access using instance of `Form1` as the error suggest.

I would rather suggest to make the Dictionary `Non-Static`:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> documents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Then your current code would work as is. I don't find rationale for Dictionary to be defined `static`

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is `static`, so you can just use the type name:

```
Form1.documents.Add(pageGuid, addcapitulo.blankRtfText);
```